# Ubuntu - web server not reachable on open port

Tags: ubuntu, portforwarding

Although I've confirmed that application Atlassian Confluence is running on port 8090 and the port has been forwarded, I'm unable to access the Atlassian Confluence Application using the External IP:

Here's my Configuration:

1. Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
2. Static IP address - XXX.YYY.ZZZ.XYZ (ifconfig -> eth0 -> inet addr)
3. Atlassian Confluence 5.8.15 (executed as user confluence)
4. ISP - Frontier Communications (Residential Account)
5. Router & Modem - Netgear 7550

I've confirmed that Confluence is UP & running by accessing the manager from both the following URLs:

1. localhost:8090/dashboard.action
2. XXX.YYY.ZZZ.XYZ:8090/dashboard.action

I've disabled ALL firewalls with the command: **sudo ufw disable**

I've confirmed that the Port 8090 is OPEN by using the tool: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Here's the output from running the command: **netstat -l | grep LISTEN**

```
tcp        0      0 localhost:8005          *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:8009                  *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:http-alt              *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:ipp           *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:postgresql    *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:8095               [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 localhost:8000          [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 localhost:8020          [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:8090               [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

External IP Address (retrieved by looking up the Router Login Page & executing "What is my IP" on Chrome): 123.456.789.111

Although the application is up & running, I'm unable to access it when I attempt to access using my External IP: http://123.456.789.111:8090/dashboard.action

I've spent countless hours figuring out why this doesn't work. What am I missing? Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solution Found: It turns out that I'm able to access the WebServer from outside of my home, and not while I'm accessing from within the home.

The workaround was to add the IP Address (internal IP of the machine) in /etc/hosts.